# How to find the text storage location of the firepad editor and how to clear the editor

Tags: javascript, firepad

I'm trying to create a custom editor for my personel need, Is there any way to delete the data which was entered by me before  when I refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but if you just want to clear the text on page load, you can do something like:

```
firepad.on('ready', function() {
  firepad.setText('');
});
```